# Leaky Shower Drain...Caulk or Replace?

Tags: shower, leak, drain, caulking

I have been experiencing a leak onto my first-floor ceiling from my shower. It only happens when someone is standing in the shower, making me think it's likely a drain issue caused by pressure rather the faucet or shower head.

I've opened the strainer and found a rotten-looking light gray gasket just sitting on top of a hard black plastic/rubber pice that surrounds the PVC. I've included the image below.

My question is whether it makes sense for my next step to be to try caulking around the seam where the flange and shower base meet (and the flange/black plastic and black plastic/PVC meet) or whether I should try to remove the drain, clean and re-caulk. I'd like to take my best shot without calling in professional help.

Guidance and advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Caulk is not a plumbing solution, and was never the right way to install a drain. (Plumber's putty is also on its way to the bin of history, having been supplanted by more reliable and less messy synthetic gaskets.) You need new gaskets or an entirely new assembly.

The only difficult part about tub plumbing is usually access. If you can get to the area in question, the rest is somewhat academic. Parts are generally fairly standardized and information abounds.